# Letsencrypt certificate upgrade issue

Tags: lets-encrypt

On Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, I am trying to upgrade letsencrypt certificate by using 
./letsencrypt-auto renew --dry-run and its giving below error

```
Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt", line 7, in <module>
    from certbot.main import main
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from acme import jose
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/acme/jose/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from acme.jose.interfaces import JSONDeSerializable
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/acme/jose/interfaces.py", line 9, in <module>
    from acme.jose import util
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/acme/jose/util.py", line 4, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces import RSABackend
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import plistlib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 62, in <module>
    import datetime
ImportError: No module named datetime
```

Can you please help here

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
rm -rf /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt
```

and try again.

Comment: Bad style. Never ever just post shell commands anyway. How can you advice to `rm -rf` ANYTHING without explaining what's the consequence? For me, it doesn't even do the trick but just triggers "virtualenv: not found".
I recommend you shut up for a year and lurk moar.

Comment: @MelchiorBlausand While I sort of agree with your comment, you shouldn't call people names or disregard the [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting the virtualenv bin directory and re-running the certbot-auto command, which will cause certbot to re-install dependencies. To find the location of the directory, look at the first line of the error response:
`Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt`. This location will vary.

Accordingly, deleting `/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/` should remove the installed dependencies and got the certs but up and running.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (Linux Debian 3.16.64-2):

mv /opt/eff.org/certbot /opt/eff.org/certbot.old

certbot-auto